# How to configure a selenium driver such that no more than n requests are made every minute?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am scraping a website and found, through trial and error, that as long as I make less than 31 requests per minute, I will not be rate limited.

Is it possible to configure selenium in such a way that it does not make more than 30 requests every minute?

Comment: Could you post your code trails what you have tried to achieve this goal?

Comment: without seeing your code, I would suggest to add waits before sending a request. Add a timer around your request and check how much time a single request takes and then add the necessary waits.

Comment: What do you mean by making a request? Getting a page? I am asking because each page generates arbitrary number of request to the resources like pictures, scripts, etc.